# Android ScrollView VS ListView show many dynamic items

Tags: android, listview, out-of-memory, scrollview, heap-memory

There is object array received from server
there are two ways to show items :

- Adapt Objects To ListView
- Use Scroll View

So If I use scroll View and add items programmatically, There are some Questions:

1. Does Adding Items Programmatically Cause Out Of Memory ?
2. Does It Need To Remove Items from memory ? or it will remove automatic after onDestroy Called or Items moved out of screen?

Regards

Comment: Better go for a `ListView` it will just use as many view objects as are needed for one screen.

Comment: If you have many items you will have oom. You must release views when they disapear of the screen. That's why you need to use an adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data set is large, a ListView won't stop OOMs by itself, you will have to avoid loading the entire data set in memory by using a CusorAdapter backed by some non-memory data store (like a sql database).

A ListView will reduce the amount of memory that the Views use to represent the data to the user, since it will only initialise Views that the user can see (and recycle Views if possible when the user scrolls).

Since only the Views visible are loaded with a ListView, performance should* also be better since the layout process will be quicker.

In most cases, a ListView would be better for this type of thing.

(*) If the adapter's getView or bindView e.t.c. are complex, or each row in the list has its own view type, the scrolling performance could actually be worse.

Answer (score 0):

Listview is the Best case for you. and I will prefer to use volly library of android . It is easy to use and very handy and helpfull.